Setting up HotReload for iOS in Visual Studio
I'm trying to setup HotReload to test my .NET MAUI app in Visual Studio 2022. It looks like they've changed the way this is set up and we now need to use an API key to connect to Apple to create/download a provisioning profile for development purposes.
Though I (try to) follow the instructions on Apple's site, I keep getting the following error in Visual Studio. I also followed instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/apple-account-management?view=net-maui-9.0

I'm confused about a few things:

When I created my Apple developer account, I did create it as a company and we do have an ID assigned to us as a company. In our distribution provisioning profile, my company's name is listed. With that said, in this setup window in Visual Studio, they keep referring to an "Enterprise" or "Individual" account. I'm not sure which to pick. We never signed up for a separate "Enterprise" API access program. Am I to choose "Individual" or "Enterprise"? BTW, I tried both and got the same error popup -- see below. Also, please notice that I created the API key under "Team Keys" under "Users and Access" so I picked the "Enterprise" account.



I did create a new API Key and downloaded an auth_some_id.p8 file and I'm entering the information as shown in the image below. For private key path, I'm pointing to the p8 file I downloaded. That's depicted with (3) in the image below.


I'm also confused about the error message I get. It refers to creating JWT tokens and there's also a section about that on Apple documentation. Am I to create a JWT token as described in Apple documentation. If so, where do I specify it in Visual Studio or will entering the correct info in this setup window in VS2022 automatically handle the JWT token for me?


What am I doing wrong here?
